# Can't use process.env values in cloud functions arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I spent a whole hour figuring out why my function was not working, and reduced the problem to this simple code:

```js
import {onDocumentCreated} from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

export const myfunction = onDocumentCreated(
    `users/{uid}/${process.env.TEST_KEY}/{id}`,
    (event) => {
        console.log(process.env.TEST_KEY);
    }
);
```

(`.env` file is containing `TEST_KEY=data`)

As you can see the first argument is the path to the collection to "listen" to, and is using a string literal (which doesn't work).

Now if I change the above to

```js
import {onDocumentCreated} from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';

export const myfunction = onDocumentCreated(
    `users/{uid}/data/{id}`,
    (event) => {
        console.log(process.env.TEST_KEY);
    }
);
```

Then it works as expected and console logs `data` when I push a document inside the firestore.

`process.env.TEST_KEY` is resolved inside the function but is not in the string literal.. Why?

---

**Edit**: It seems to be a quirk about firebase-functions.
I found this [GH Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/1094) which could be related.

Answer (score 1):

You may file a bug in this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) if you're already using this feature and not working properly the Product Team will look into this. However, there is no ETA for it.

Steps for filing a bug:

- Select the relevant category and provide a concise title.
- Describe the issue with detailed steps and include any relevant information or code snippets.
- Attach logs or error messages, if applicable.
- Submit the support ticket and wait for a response.
- Remember to provide as much relevant information as possible. Alternatively, check Firebase documentation or community forums for existing solutions.